# How to assign CTRL+F1 to sp_whoisactive in ssms 2012?

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2012

When I go to Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard and
Type in Query.Sp_whoisactive
Press shortcut keys: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
Click Assign.

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, It still calls Help.

Comment: I had the same issue, I've logged it on [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/737453/sql-server-management-studio-2012-ctrl-f1-launches-help-not-query-shortcut-code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on Tools > Options.  Then navigate to Environment > Keyboard > Query Shortcuts. In the stored procedure column next to Ctrl+F1, type Sp_whoisactive.

Next navigate to Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard > Keyboard, and find the command Query.CustomSP1. Assign the shortcut Ctrl+F1. Then search for the command Help.ViewHelp and remove the mapping for Ctrl+F1 there.

Comment: I still can't assign Ctrl+F1 combination. But Ctrl+3 works

Answer (score 0):

In Sql Server 2012, control + F1 is assigned to View Help (Check the Help menu in SSMS). I don't think now we can re-assign to some other functionality. But still I'm not sure why the Control+F1 option is provided in Query Short cuts. So there may be a provision to re-assign this also. Not sure, we have to explore the new features in Sql Server 2012.

Comment: This is not true, or at least not always: I've used Ctrl-F1 for `sp_whoisactive` in MSSS 2012 and 2014.