# Ctrl-F1 shortcut stopped working in SSMS 2014

Tags: ssms, keyboard-shortcuts

I've had the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> query shortcut bound to `sp_whoisactive` for years (this technique is described in [How to assign CTRL+F1 to sp_whoisactive in ssms 2012?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16182/how-to-assign-ctrlf1-to-sp-whoisactive-in-ssms-2012)).  A few days ago, it stopped working. If I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>, SQL Studio now launches Books Online in Internet Explorer.  Has anyone else seen this problem?  Is there a fix?

I confirmed that the shortcut it still set.  Changing the shortcut does not fix the problem, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> still launches BoL.  Cycling SQL Studio has had no effect.

FWIW, this happened after IT restarted the server while I was logged in, so SSMS did not shut down clean.

I can of course use another keyboard shortcut (though sadly it seems <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd> is hardcoded to sp_help), it just bothers my OCD to use a different shortcut for the same command on different machines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a long shot: I think your Management Studio has for some reason changed the keyboard mappings to the 2012/2014 default setup, which is more similar to the regular Visual Studio apps. This changed as of SQL Server 2012 so, among other things, Ctrl+F1 now opens Books On-Line.

To verify if this is the case for you, you probably won't be able to execute queries using Ctrl+E or view estimated query plans using Ctrl+L.

I found a way to reset the keyboard shortcuts to the "classic" setup and wrote a [blog post](http://sqlsunday.com/2014/05/11/changes-in-ssms-keyboard-shortcuts/) about it a while ago. The short version is:

- Open the "Tools" menu i SSMS,
- Select "Import and Export settings...",
- Select the "Reset all settings" option, click "Next",
- On the last page of the wizard, you have the option to back up your current settings. I would recommend you to do this.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for taking the shot, but it doesn't look like this is the case: Ctrl-L still works.  I may end up trying "Reset all settings," but there are a number of little things I like to tweak which I'd hate to redo if I can help it.

Comment: In the "reset all settings" dialog, there's an option to export your settings to an XML file, which you can then selectively edit and re-import. I use it reguarly to copy my settings across different SSMS clients.